# How to get coordinates of window client area

Tags: c#, winapi

I can get the coordinates of a windows entire area, and the coordinates of the client area using the GetClientRect and GetWindowRect Win32 calls.  My problem is that the GetClientRect always returns 0,0 for the top left.  How do I figure out what the actual client region is relative to the window rect?

Comment: If you're using WinForms (and based on your comments below, it looks like you are), you shouldn't be using PInvoke for this.  Use `Control.ClientRectangle` and `Control.Bounds`.

Comment: I need to use PInvoke because I'm getting coordinates of a window in another application.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [ClientToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183434(VS.85).aspx) to get the coordinates of the upper left (0,0) point in screen coordinates.  The RECT returned by GetClientRect will be appropriate to get you the lower right corner (just add to the POINT set by ClientToScreen).

Comment: I don't understand why this is an accepted answer. This maps the client rect relative to the screen rect. The question asks for the client rect relative to the window rect (which, in Win32, is the rectangle encompassing all window borders/trim, outside the client rect.)

Comment: The answer is correct. The WindowRect is already in absolute screen coordinates. After mapping the ClientRect (which has it's top left corner at 0,0) to screen coordinates with ClientToScreen() or with MapWindowPoints() they are both in screen coordinates.

Answer (score 6):

Use ClientToScreen to convert the client coordinates to screen coordinates.  The window rect (GetWindowRect) is already in screen coordinates, and includes the non-client area (borders, caption, etc)

Comment: and this was the crucial bit I was missing; *and includes the non-client area (borders, caption, etc).* Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

And if you are working with WinForms then you can use [PointToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx) instead of ClientToScreen for solution proposed by Reed Copsey.

Answer (score 2):

The relation between window rect (with borders etc) and the client rect (inside borders) is most easily found using [AdjustWindowRectEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Get the window style and ex style of the window, and call that function, to see how much border is on each side.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [MapWindowPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145046.aspx) function to convert an entire RECT to screen coordinates at once.

Comment: This is found at `Control.RectangleToScreen` and its cousin, `Control.RectangleToClient`.