# Need to know a "Local to screen Coordinate" function

Tags: .net, infragistics

I would like to have a tooltop displayed on a textbox under a certain situation.

The InfragisticsTooltipManager control gives me the ability to display a Tooptip at a certain coordinates.

I would like to display the tip so that the arrow part of the baloon tooltip is pointing to the textbox and so the tooltip is visible regardless of the position of the textbox on the screen. This means that if the textbox is at the very top of the srcen, the tooptip would need to be displayed below the textbox, else above it.

For now, I would be happy if someone could point out the Local To Screen Coordinate function I would need to determine where the tool tip needed to be displayed if I always wanted to display it on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these methods are usually called ClientToScreen and ScreenToClient.

see here: [How to get coordinates of window client area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242266/how-to-get-coordinates-of-window-client-area)